# How do I use brace expansions with variabiles and functions?

Tags: bash

I wanted a character to be repeated n times based on a variable or function and I ended up using the *seq* command but that's only because I don't understand how to use brace expansions with variables or functions. **{1..$num} or {1..$(num)}**

```
#function w/ seq
num() { echo $(shuf -i 0-50 -n 1); }
repeat() { for i in $(seq 1 $(num));do echo -n "$1";done; }
repeat -
```

if you modify the above function to a variable that works as well.

```
#variable w/ seq
num=$(echo $(shuf -i 0-50 -n 1))
repeat() { for i in $(seq 1 $num);do echo -n "$1";done; }
repeat -
```

My question is, **how can I use brace expansions to get the same results using a variable or function?**

what I tried didn't work...

```
#function with brace expansion
num() { echo $(shuf -i 0-50 -n 1); }
repeat() { for i in {1..$(num)};do echo -n "$1";done; }
repeat -
```

and as a variable...

```
#variable with brace expansion
num=$(echo $(shuf -i 0-50 -n 1))
repeat() { for i in {1..$num};do echo -n "$1";done; }
repeat -
```

The output is just the one character that resides at $1 when *repeat* is called... regardless of the range of $num or $(num) being 0-50, I know I'll get a 0 or 1 at some point...

It'll function but only if I replace $num or $(num) with a fixed number. Doesn't seem to work with a variable or function in place.

Also am I using these brace expansions correctly when I think of them as a range or a bit like *seq* or a sequence?
thanks

**EDIT**

short answer you can't use variables with brace expansions in bash without the use of some trickery

looks like the best option is to use *seq*, C-style loop or use zsh

```
#C-style
num() { "5"; }
for((i=1; i<=$(num); i++)); do (num);done

or

num=5
for((i=1; i<=num; i++)); do echo "$num";done
```

Comment: Paste your script to https://shellcheck.net/ ... not being a regular bash user myself, that site helps with syntax and other issues with the script, kinda like a lint checker.

Comment: well that works thanks @PaulT. at least from that site it says variables can't be used with brace expansions I guess seq was the best option to use, thanks for the help